# Apache Druid throwing network error in console

Tags: druid

When we are trying to query a datasource , the query runs for 5+ mins and throws ***network error*** in console. We are trying to fetch some huge result in millions. Is this some limitation in druid, where we can't fetch huge records? Other aggregated queries are running fine and producing results.

```
SELECT * FROM "datasource"
WHERE "__time" >= TIMESTAMP '2021-06-21' and "__time" <= TIMESTAMP '2021-06-23' and consumerid=1234
```

[image]

```
Segment Granularity: DAY
Query Granularity : DAY
Segments Created: 736
Avg Segment Size: 462 MB
Total Datasource Size: 340.28 GB
Replicated Size: 680.55 GB
```

secondary partition: single_dim (consumerid)

Is there some way to overcome this Issue?

I've tried this via API also, after 5.30 seconds it throws error.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://druiddev-druid.int.org/druid/v2/sql' --header 'Authorization: Basic Username/p' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{
    "query": "SELECT * FROM datasource WHERE consumerid=1234 and buydate='\''01/01/2021'\''",
    "resultFormat" : "csv",
    "batchSize":20480

}' > output.dat

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 17.9M    0 17.9M    0   165  58699      0 --:--:--  0:05:20 --:--:-- 86008
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)
```